# OleVariant and String assignments in Delphi 5

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-5

I have a Delphi 5 legacy application and there's a part in which a "string" value is been assigned to an "OleVariant" variable. Something like this:

```
var
   X: OleVariant;
   S: string;
Begin
   S:= ‘This string should contain 200 characters as per design’;
   X:= S; 
End;
```

If the length of “S” is greater than 128, then the value of “X” gets truncated and it only holds a maximum of 128 characters.

Is there a way to overcome this?

I believe there is a way, because if I create my own demo application from scratch (in the same PC, with the same Delphi 5), it allows me to pass longer string values and no truncating is done.

Maybe it is something about the project settings or compiler directives. I have played around with this idea, but I have no workaround yet.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Demo:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  X: OleVariant;
  S: string;
begin
  //in the Edit I pass a string of 240 chars, let's say;
  S:= Edit1.Text;
  X:= S;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Length(X)) + ' : ' + IntToStr(Length(S)));
  //this showmessage shows "128 : 240"
end;
```

Comment: Please copy and paste *real* code that demonstrates what you claim. I expect some code that assigns an *actual* 200-character-long `string` variable, and some code that measures the length of an `OleVariant` value and prints the value `128`. If that's not how you determined that there is a problem, then please describe what you *did* to conclude that `X` is only 128 characters long.

Comment: Look at the description. I added some more code. You can also notice the problem if you debug and trace the application (inspect X and S when debugging).

Comment: I tried this in Delphi 4 (Windows 95), and the string is *not* truncated.

Comment: Don't trust the tooltips in the debugger. They are truncated at 128 for variants, but not for strings. I still can't quite believe that the variant doesn't actually hold the full string.

Comment: I tested in Delphi 5 (Build 6.18 Update Pack 1) and the code works fine.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand and you are using OleVariant also?

Comment: Let me explain again: if you create that code from scratch it works ok. But, if I embed that code in a legacy application that i have it does not work. I need to know what might be enforcing the "truncating" in the legacy application.

Comment: @Yanniel: Then it is time to debug! Make a copy of your project, and remove one part at a time, until the project is basically a fresh VCL application.

Comment: I think we are going to need to see the real code. The code in the question clearly works fine. I'm fairly sure your legacy application does not have TForm1.Button1Click in it and so this code in the Q is the "from scratch" code that works fine. Now, as for the truncation in the debugger, that's a known problem with the debugger, but the contents of the variant are fine.

Comment: Tested with D5. works fine. The only thing that can affect the string length is using `{$H-}` or `{$LONGSTRINGS OFF}` but this will truncate to 255 (`ShortString`). Make sure no other unit is re-defining `OleVariant` e.g. `type OleVariant = string[128]`.  define 'X' as `X: System.OleVariant` and test again... HTH

Comment: Guys, I thank you for your help.

I cannot disclose the code of my legacy application (because it does not belong to me). Besides, it contains over one million lines of code.

Comment: @kobik `type OleVariant = string[128]`. That would be pretty nasty!!  ;-) A devious mind.

Comment: @Yanniel OK, but I think you should have had enough feedback now to convince you that the problem is in your code and not in the Delphi RTL.

Comment: I actually did put a Button1 in my legacy application. The form is not called TForm1, but that shouldn’t matter. In my legacy application, it truncates the value after the assignment was done.

Comment: I never thought that it was a Delphi RTL issue. I think this is about inline compiler options of some sort ({$H+}, {$I+}), my legacy application is full of them. I hoping just that somebody experienced this in the past.

Comment: Just in case I am going to look for type OleVariant = string[128]

Comment: I just checked it, nobody redefined the OleVariant type. thanks god :-)

Comment: So then I would try to put the breakpoints wherever you set your variant variable and try to watch the value of it in debugger through the `VarToStr` function (with a hope it's possible to allow function calls by watches with D5).

Answer (score 2):

Try this *OleVariantToString* and *StringToOleVariant* functions at http://www.foxbase.ru/delphi/vzaimnye-preobrazovaniya-olevariant-i-string.htm

They work perfectly for me.

```
uses Classes, Variants;
function OleVariantToString(const Value: OleVariant): string;
  var ss: TStringStream;
      Size: integer;
      Data: PByteArray;
begin
  Result:='';
  if Length(Value) = 0 then Exit;
  ss:=TStringStream.Create;
  try
    Size := VarArrayHighBound (Value, 1) - VarArrayLowBound(Value, 1) + 1;
    Data := VarArrayLock(Value);
    try
      ss.Position := 0;
      ss.WriteBuffer(Data^, Size);
      ss.Position := 0;
      Result:=ss.DataString;
    finally
      VarArrayUnlock(Value);
    end;
  finally
    ss.Free;
  end;
end;

function StringToOleVariant(const Value: string): OleVariant;
  var Data: PByteArray;
      ss: TStringStream;
begin
  Result:=null;
  if Value='' then Exit;
  ss:=TStringStream.Create(Value);
  try
    Result := VarArrayCreate ([0, ss.Size - 1], varByte);
    Data := VarArrayLock(Result);
    try
      ss.Position := 0;
      ss.ReadBuffer(Data^, ss.Size);
    finally
      VarArrayUnlock(Result);
    end;
  finally
    ss.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

One explanation is that `OleVariant` holds the entire string but that you are looking at the debugger tooltip. In older Delphi versions the debugger tooltip truncates at 128 characters for strings held in a variant.  Note that the debugger tooltip for a plain `string` does not truncate at this length. Try showing the variant in a dialog box and you will see that the entire string is present.

I checked this out on Delphi 6 and there was no truncation with your code (other than the debugger tooltip). Andreas did likewise on Delphi 4 and Rodrigo did so with Delphi 5. I cannot imagine that it could really be the case that strings in a Delphi 5 `OleVariant` are truncated at 128 characters.

If you really are seeing what you are report then I can think of the following explanations:

- Your code is erroneously truncating the string, but you have not yet found the code that does this. Only you can debug that.
- You have a local bug private to your Delphi installation. Are you by any chance compiling your own RTL?

Comment: It's not a "variant", it's an "OleVariant". I did use a showmessage and it was still truncated. Note: the "variant" in my case works just fine; nonetheless the "OleVariant" fails.

Comment: I'm using `OleVariant` in my D6 trials.

Comment: Guys, I thank you for your help. I cannot disclose the code of my legacy application (because it does not belong to me). Besides, it contains over one million lines of code.

Comment: This is nothing trivial: it’s not the debugger (I can assure you that); I can even dump the OleVariant variable to a text file and the content remains truncated. So, it’s not the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I made this work. Summary: instead of filling an “OleVariant” with a “string”; I filled a “Variant” and then typecasted that “Variant” to “OleVariant”. Take a look at the code below so that you can get the idea.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  //X: OleVariant;
  X: Variant;
  S: string;
begin
  //Let's say in the Edit1 I pass a string of 240 chars,
  S:= Edit1.Text;
  X:= S;

  //ShowMessage(IntToStr(Length(X)) + ' : ' + IntToStr(Length(S)));
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Length(OleVariant(X))) + ' : ' + IntToStr(Length(S)));
  //This ShowMessage shows "128 : 240"
end;
```

Honestly, I don’t know for sure why this makes a difference, but it does. It works ok now.

Thanks a lot for your help folks!

Comment: This is because casting a string to `OleVariant` will convert it to `WideString` (COM-Compatible). one of your units might be messing up with one of the oleaut32 `Sysxxx` functions (probably in the initialization section), or you have a custom memory manager.